# Check if a Polygon Feature is completely enclosed by another GeoJSON features in OpenLayers 4

Tags: javascript, openlayers, maps

I have a map which is implemented using Openlayers 4. It loads a GeoJSON vector which defines the boundaries of a particular country. The user is allowed to draw and edit polygons to define subregions of this countries which will be saved to DB as GeoJSON data. I need to check if the polygon drawn by the user is completly within the boundaries of the country. How can i achieve this. I am adding the code snippet where i capture the subregion layer polygon drawn by the user here.

```
feature.on('change', function(event) {
          var format = new ol.format.GeoJSON({featureProjection: 'EPSG:3857'});

          var subregion_features = format.writeFeatures(vector.getSource().getFeatures());

          //code to check if the newly drawn polygon is inside the master layer (whole country layer)

        });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) library, which can be used to do all sorts of operations between geometries.  For instance, you could write a **MultiPolygon** geometry containing all your sub regions and use the **contains** method of the JSTS [Geometry](http://bjornharrtell.github.io/jsts/doc/api/jsts.geom.Geometry.html) class.

There's an [example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html) that features JSTS with OpenLayers.  It shows how to use the **buffer** method, you could start from there to learn how to use the **contains** method in JSTS.  You would need to convert the geometry object from OL3 to JSTS first.  That's shown in the example.

```
// convert the OpenLayers geometry to a JSTS geometry
var jstsGeom = parser.read(feature.getGeometry());
```

Therefore:

```
var contains = jstsGeom.contains(jstsGeom2); // should work
```

With this, you would be able to check if the drawn geometry is inside the exact boundaries of the regions

Answer (score 0):

An example how to check it in OpenLayers 6.x version and typescript:

```typescript
let xy:any = this.getCenterOfExtent(feature.getGeometry()?.getExtent());
let insideFeature:boolean = selectedFeature.getGeometry().containsXY(xy[0],xy[1]));

//...

getCenterOfExtent(extent:Extent){
    var X = extent[0] + (extent[2]-extent[0])/2;
    var Y = extent[1] + (extent[3]-extent[1])/2;
    return [X, Y];
}
```

Probably there will be an easier solution with newer versions of Openlayers in the future.